# rspec - how to have examples without both 'describe' and 'it'

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given the following working code:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'dec_to_hex'
describe "Should convert 20 to 32" do
  it "should convert correctly" do
    converter("20").should == 32
  end 
end
```

Why can't I have the actual test as either

```
describe "Should convert 20 to 32" do
    converter("20").should == 32
end
# This simply doesn't run the test, it gets ignored!
```

or

```
it "should convert correctly" do
  converter("20").should == 32
end 
# This gives undefined method `it'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use both 'describe' and 'it' blocks when using RSpec. The internal reason is described in the docs (http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/frames) as follows:

"The describe method creates an ExampleGroup. Within the block passed to describe you can declare examples using the it method.

Under the hood, an example group is a class in which the block passed to describe is evaluated. The blocks passed to it are evaluated in the context of an instance of that class."